# how to connect socket.io 1.0 in ios client?

Tags: ios, io, socket.io

how to connect socket.io 1.0 in ios client?
Also i use the following code to connect using iOS stream classes:-

```
  - (void) initNetworkCommunication {

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)(@"23.236.52.90"), 3000 , &readStream, &writeStream);

_inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
_outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[_inputStream setDelegate:self];
[_outputStream setDelegate:self];
[_inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[_outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[_inputStream open];
[_outputStream open];

 }

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

switch (streamEvent) {

    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        NSLog(@"Stream opened");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

        if (theStream == _inputStream) {

            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            unsigned int len;

            while ([_inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [_inputStream read:buffer maxLength:1024];
                if (len) {

                    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    if (nil != output) {

                        NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                        [self messageReceived:output];

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;


    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

        NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
        break;

    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

        [theStream close];
        [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        theStream = nil;

        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Unknown event");
}

}
```

though i receive buffer with data in it, i always get len as 0 . my server uses socket.io 1.1.0.

buffer response :-

```
(uint8_t [1024]) buffer = {
  [0] = 'H'
  [1] = '\xd7'
  [2] = '\xff'
  [3] = '\xbf'
  [4] = '\x11'
  [5] = '\x01'
  [6] = '\xe2'
  [7] = '\x8f'
  [8] = '\x9c'
  [9] = '\xde'
  [10] = '\xc0'
  [11] = '\x01'
  [12] = '\xc8'
  [13] = '\xeb'
  [14] = '\xc0'
  [15] = '\x01'
  [16] = 'G'
  [17] = 'O'
  [18] = '\x84'
  [19] = '\x06'
  [20] = '\xbe'
  [21] = '\x02'
  [22] = '\xe2'
  [23] = '\x8f'
  [24] = '_'
  [25] = '\0'
  [26] = '\0'
  [27] = '\0'
  [28] = 'z'
  [29] = '\0'
  [30] = '\0'
  [31] = '\0'
  [32] = ' '
  [33] = '\xe3'
  [34] = '\xc0'
  [35] = '\x01'
  [36] = '\xce'
  [37] = '\0'
  [38] = '\xe2'
  [39] = '\x8f'
  [40] = '\xc8'
  [41] = '+'
  [42] = '\x02'
  [43] = '\0'
  [44] = 'X'
  [45] = '\xf7'
  [46] = '\xff'
  [47] = '\xff'
  [48] = '\0'
  [49] = '\0'
  [50] = '\0'
  [51] = '\0'
  [52] = '\xbe'
  [53] = '\x02'
  [54] = '\xe2'
  [55] = '\x8f'
  [56] = 'e'
  [57] = '\0'
  [58] = '\0'
  [59] = '\0'
  [60] = '\xc8'
  [61] = '\xeb'
  [62] = '\xc0'
  [63] = '\x01'
  [64] = '\0'
  [65] = '\0'
  [66] = '\0'
  [67] = '\0'
  [68] = '\xe2'
  [69] = '\x98'
  [70] = '\xe1'
  [71] = '\x8f'
  [72] = 'x'
  [73] = '\xd8'
  [74] = '\xff'
  [75] = '\xbf'
  [76] = '\xbc'
  [77] = '\xfc'
  [78] = '\xe3'
  [79] = '\x8f'
  [80] = '\x88'
  [81] = '\xd7'
  [82] = '\xff'
  [83] = '\xbf'
  [84] = '\x0e'
  [85] = '\x99'
  [86] = '\xe1'
  [87] = '\x8f'
  [88] = '\xbc'
  [89] = '\xfc'
  [90] = '\xe3'
  [91] = '\x8f'
  [92] = '0'
  [93] = '\xa1'
  [94] = '\xe3'
  [95] = '\x8f'
  [96] = ' '
  [97] = '\xe3'
  [98] = '\xc0'
  [99] = '\x01'
  [100] = '\xcc'
  [101] = 'V'
  [102] = '\xe4'
  [103] = '\x8f'
  [104] = '\x01'
  [105] = '\0'
  [106] = '\0'
  [107] = '\0'
  [108] = '\xc4'
  [109] = '\x97'
  [110] = '\xe1'
  [111] = '\x8f'
  [112] = '\xa8'
  [113] = '\xd7'
  [114] = '\xff'
  [115] = '\xbf'
  [116] = '\x90'
  [117] = '\xc5'
  [118] = '\xf2'
  [119] = '\b'
  [120] = '\0'
  [121] = '\xd0'
  [122] = '\xbf'
  [123] = '\b'
  [124] = '\x04'
  [125] = '\0'
  [126] = '\0'
  [127] = '\0'
  [128] = '\x03'
  [129] = '\0'
  [130] = '\0'
  [131] = '\0'
  [132] = '\0'
  [133] = '\0'
  [134] = '\0'
  [135] = '\0'
  [136] = '\0'
  [137] = '\xbf'
  [138] = '\xd1'
  [139] = '\b'
  [140] = '\0'
  [141] = '\xbf'
  [142] = '\xd1'
  [143] = '\b'
  [144] = '('
  [145] = '\xd8'
  [146] = '\xff'
  [147] = '\xbf'
  [148] = '\xc2'
  [149] = '\a'
  [150] = '\xe6'
  [151] = '\x01'
  [152] = '\x90'
  [153] = '\xc5'
  [154] = '\xf2'
  [155] = '\b'
  [156] = '@'
  [157] = '\0'
  [158] = '\0'
  [159] = '\0'
  [160] = '\x01'
  [161] = '\0'
  [162] = '\0'
  [163] = '\0'
  [164] = '\t'
  [165] = 'a'
  [166] = '\xe3'
  [167] = '\b'
  [168] = '\0'
  [169] = '\xdf'
  [170] = '\xaf'
  [171] = '\b'
  [172] = '\0'
  [173] = '\xa0'
  [174] = '\xaf'
  [175] = '\b'
  [176] = 'H'
  [177] = '\xd8'
  [178] = '\xff'
  [179] = '\xbf'
  [180] = 'v'
  [181] = '\x03'
  [182] = '\xe6'
  [183] = '\x01'
  [184] = '\xbb'
  [185] = '\xff'
  [186] = '\xe5'
  [187] = '\x01'
  [188] = '@'
  [189] = '\0'
  [190] = '\0'
  [191] = '\0'
  [192] = '\xd8'
  [193] = '\xd7'
  [194] = '\xff'
  [195] = '\xbf'
  [196] = 'x'
  [197] = '\xd8'
  [198] = '\xff'
  [199] = '\xbf'
  [200] = '\0'
  [201] = '\xb5'
  [202] = '\xd1'
  [203] = '\b'
  [204] = '\0'
  [205] = '\n'
  [206] = '\0'
  [207] = '\0'
  [208] = '\x18'
  [209] = '\xd8'
  [210] = '\xff'
  [211] = '\xbf'
  [212] = '\xc6'
  [213] = '\x9c'
  [214] = '\xe1'
  [215] = '\x8f'
  [216] = '\xbb'
  [217] = '\xff'
  [218] = '\xe5'
  [219] = '\x01'
  [220] = '\x1c'
  [221] = '\0'
  [222] = '\0'
  [223] = '\0'
  [224] = 'p'
  [225] = '\xec'
  [226] = '\xe3'
  [227] = '\x8f'
  [228] = '\0'
  [229] = '\0'
  [230] = '\0'
  [231] = '\0'
  [232] = '\0'
  [233] = '\xd5'
  [234] = '\xaf'
  [235] = '\b'
  [236] = '@'
  [237] = '\0'
  [238] = '\0'
  [239] = '\0'
  [240] = '\x02'
  [241] = '\0'
  [242] = '\0'
  [243] = '\0'
  [244] = '\xc2'
  [245] = '\a'
  [246] = '\xe6'
  [247] = '\x01'
  [248] = '\0'
  [249] = '\xbf'
  [250] = '\xd1'
  [251] = '\b'
  [252] = '\0'
  [253] = '\xd0'
  [254] = '\xbf'
  [255] = '\b'
  ...
}
```